# MsiPatchRemovalList on MSI uninstall

Tags: wix, windows-installer, msi-patch

I have a CustomAction inside my MSI Project with a condition of **MsiPatchRemovalList**, this is because i need to execute this for each patch uninstall process.

This is working properly, when i execute the uninstall patch it is executing the CustomAction and do the process refere to the specific patch without error.

The problem is when i uninstall the MSI, all patches are uninstalled but the event is not fired.

Note: execute in the MSI uninstall is not an option because this event need to do a process specific for each patch

Update:
The custom action process is take the MSIPATCHREMOVE element to know the Patch Guid and create a register key using this guid, in the register to have a historic to know what patch was uninstalled

Comment: Could you explain what the custom actions do so we can see if there are alternative solutions? Maybe you are just adding some license keys or tweaking some settings somehow?

Comment: i add the process to the question

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to have a condition of (MsiPatchRemovalList or REMOVE="ALL").

If you need to know which patches have been applied to the product when it is being uninstalled then you'd need to incorporate a call to MsiEnumPatches (or equivalent), before the install I assume, and do something such as pass them on the uninstall command line:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370099(v=vs.85).aspx

Another thing you could is for each patch to add a registry entry containing (say) its patch guid, effectively making your own list. Then you could do a registry search for each of the possible patches or your list, and set a property similar to the standard patch removal list. I haven't thought this through completely but if each patch adds something to the registry saying "I'm here" you wouldn't have to rely so much on a patch removal list because you've created your own.

Comment: but in REMOVE="ALL" i not be able to identify the PatchCode of each patch, and in this scenario the MsiPatchRemovalList is not initialized

Comment: The question implies that you want to call your custom action when the product is removed, for which the condition is REMOVE="ALL", so the custom action will be called if you add this to your condition. Since you know that all the patches are being uninstalled you can call all the patch processes you want. There is no "patch uninstall" when the product is removed because the product IS (MSI+Patches) and that's what is uninstalled. Perhaps there is some part of your situation that isn't fully described, such as the relationship between each patch and the processes you refer to.

Comment: maybe i can create a condition to create a key saying all patch was uninstalled, but if a do this, i don´t going to know if i had a patch installed. see my update in the question